# Does comparison to 'undefined` still does a global scope lookup?

Tags: javascript, scope, undefined, global, ecmascript-5

Accordigng to http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.3 `undefined` can't no longer be redefined.

**Does it imply that global lookup (to find if** `undefined` **was redefined) is not happening anymore?**

Though, it does seem to be unnecessary now :)

**UPDATE**
Of course the question is about the `strict` mode :) Thanks T.J.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not in the global scope, you still have to do a lookup for a local `undefined` variable (which could be `1`, `null`, `'fjakfjadjfjlfjsdkj'`, or any other random thing), since `undefined` is not a reserved word.  Otherwise though, a browser that supports ES5 could do so in theory, as the global `undefined` variable could never be changed.

Comment: Much better answer than mine.